# Regular expression - Cut string from the end by space but with this space

Tags: c#, regex, string

The input string for regex is a casual number of chars from another string. So it can be an incomplete part of a word at the end of the input string. Regex must cut the incomplete part of the word and the space at the end of the string. Because there must be the whole word at the end of this string. So I wrote this to cut the incomplete part of the last word (C#):

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"([^\s]*){1}$", String.Empty)
```

As you see I use the space as the mark for the regex to stop cutting. **But how to cut this space also?** It must be in the same regex because I don't want to use another regex or "Trim" functions for this simple operation. I know that it is easier to use TrimEnd but it is not graceful. So it's just academic question. :)

Comment: I beg to differ. Using a "Trim" function to remove trailing whitespace is infinitely more graceful than your regex approach.

Comment: I take it this is C# - edited to include tag.

Comment: Also, `{1}` is completely superfluous. And therefore also the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include an optional space like so:

`\s?([^\s]*){1}$`

Which can be simplified:

`\s?\S*$`

Comment: \s?\S*$ - is exactly that I need. Thanks! But the third regex cuts even the whole word at the end that isn't need. It must cuts only the incomplete words at the end. So the second regex is perfect for my task. ))

Comment: You're welcome. Your updated question is much clearer, so I removed the third Regex. Please remember to accept correct answers.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `TrimEnd()` *or* a regex improvement. Just use `Trim()`, like so:

```
s.Trim();
```

Edit: If you need to remove the last word too, and you have LINQ, you might like this:

```
string[] split = s.Split(new char[] {' '});
s = split.Take(split.Length - 1).Aggregate((m, n) => m + ' ' + n);
```

Comment: The OP wasn't very clear, but I think he needs to remove the last word AND the last space.

Comment: I fixed the first message for more understanding.